# Friend protected method in c++

Tags: c++, friend-function

I've got a class Foo that must be accessed "directly" in other class Bar. I'd like to build a little framework declaring the method of Bar (which is the friend method of Foo) protected. In this way I could build several classes children of Bar.

Gcc complains about that and it works only if the method is public.

How can I do? Example of my code:

```
class Foo;
class Bar {
    protected:
        float* internal(Foo& f);
};
class Foo {
    private:
        //some data
    public:
        //some methods
        friend float* Bar::internal(Foo& f);
};
```

Gcc message:

```
prog.cpp:4:16: error: ‘float* Bar::internal(Foo&)’ is protected
         float* internal(Foo& f);
                ^
prog.cpp:11:43: error: within this context
         friend float* Bar::internal(Foo& f);
                                           ^
```

Comment: did you try making `Foo`'s method protected?

Comment: @redFIVE Yep, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to declare class Foo a friend of class Bar (within class Bar)?

Comment: Did you try to put the definition of `Bar` before the definition of `Foo`?

Comment: @Ashalynd With your suggestion now gcc compiles the code, even if it's a bit strange because now Foo can access to every field of Bar. Wow.

Comment: @celtschk Yep, it's the same thing.

Comment: Could you include in the question the gcc error message.

Comment: Maybe I found a thing here: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2005-03/msg00172.html. It seems a "feature" of gcc4. The error is due the limited scope of the method, indeed the friend declaration suggested by Ashalynd solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it should be obvious that you can't access protected/private members of a class from another class. This is also true if you try to friend the protected/private member function. So, you can't do this unless you put the method in a public section or make `Foo` a friend of `Bar`.

You can also do this by making the entire class `Bar` a friend of `Foo`. So either do this:

```
class Bar {
protected:
    friend class Foo; // Foo can now see the internals of Bar
    float* internal(Foo& f);
 };
class Foo {
private:
    //some data
public:
    //some methods
    friend float* Bar::internal(Foo& f);
};
```

Or this:

```
class Bar {
protected:
    float* internal(Foo& f);
};
class Foo {
private:
    //some data
public:
    //some methods
    friend class Bar; // now Bar::internal has access to internals of Foo
};
```

Comment: It wasn't obvious indeed with gcc3 works without problem. I think I'll go for the Bar frined of Foo solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it so that `Foo` is only accessible by a single non-public method without complete access to `Bar`, you can create an intermediate `class` for that task.

```
class Foo;
class Bar;
class FooBar {
    friend Foo;
    friend Bar;
    Bar &bar_;
    FooBar (Bar &b) : bar_(b) {}
    float* internal(Foo &f);
};

class Foo {
    private:
        //some data
    public:
        //some methods
        friend float* FooBar::internal(Foo& f);
};
```

And now, `Bar` can call into this intermediate class in its own `protected` version of that method.

```
class Bar {
    friend FooBar;
    // some private data
    protected:
        float* internal(Foo& f) {
            FooBar fb(*this);
            return fb.internal(f);
        }
};
```